# What do you call an action that is less serious than a "crime" (that is not illegal, just against rules)?

Tags: word-request

Example sentence:

> Dying your hair pink is a __ in secondary school.

I thought of words like "offense" and "misdeed," but they don't ring quite right.

Comment: Is this against the rules or just a social issue?

Comment: The question title and body text don't match. A crime is something that is illegal, an offence (the word I was thinking of before reading the full question) is also illegal but not as serious. In a school environment, no school rules are laws, so breaking one is not illegal, although there will most likely be consequences such as being sent home, suspended, or expelled, depending on the seriousness. The question could be clarified because we don't know exactly what sense you want. Do you mean "What is a bad action called that is not illegal?" "A word for breaking the rules?", etc.?

Comment: Do you really need a noun? In everyday speech, it would be most common to say something like: *Dying your hair pink is **against the rules/not allowed** in secondary school.* Nouns to classify "against-the-rules" acts only really show up in very formal situations (like the actual school rulebook).

Comment: Would purple be okay?

Comment: I usually hear that something like that is an _infraction_ of the rules.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It depends on the context.  If you are talking about any kind of *official* disciplinary system with rules and punishments, then any of these may work:  *infraction, violation, transgression, breach, contravention* and various others.  In this case, for example:

> Dying your hair pink is a serious **transgression** of school policy.

You can also say the action itself is *banned, restricted, prohibited, forbidden, barred,* or simply *not allowed*.

> Dying your hair pink is **against school policy**.

If instead you are talking about something that goes against social or moral norms, you could use (with varying degrees of severity): *taboo, anathema, frowned on, proscribed, off limits, no-no, unmentionable, abomination, faux pas* and others:

> Smoking in restaurants, which once was common practice, is now practically [**a hanging offense**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hanging+offense) in many parts of the United States.

(edit) These terms cover a wide range of *severity*.  As mentioned in the comments, "transgression" is pretty serious, while "against the rules" is fairly mild.  Please provide more details about how "bad" you want it to sound, and I can be more specific.

Comment: "Transgression" sounds somehow *worse* than "crime" to me...

Comment: @ell  I agree that it sounds *serious*, but it's not *criminal*.  You can also temper it in various ways, e.g. *a **minor** transgression*

Comment: My school used the term "infraction"

Comment: Doesn't it sound a bit more like "misbehaviour" ?

Comment: You might want to change your third example.  In much of Europe, it is actually a crime (fine up to £200 in England for example).

Comment: _Violation_ is the most common in the US.  For school you have dress code _violations_, student code of conduct _violations_ etc.  In all of the schools my kids have been to the handbook references them as such.  Breaking a law or regulation that is not a crime such as speeding is a moving _violation_.

Comment: @MartinBonner  noted, but the example specifies the United States, and it's also a deliberate *hyperbole*(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hyperbole).

Comment: Who said there were any school rules? There was no mention of school rules or regulations. Transgression is religious sounding to me.

Comment: @Lambie from OP: "Dying your hair pink is a __ in secondary school." And I agree about the religious part.

Answer (score 56):

**Infraction** could work here.  An infraction can refer to a crime but it is a very minor one that would generally only result in a fine.

Comment: Perhaps you mean infraction of a school rule.

Comment: Given the question and the body, this seems the best answer, but, at least in the US, there are several layers of legal issues. For example, breaking a rule may mean you broke a policy or that you broke a law. Both could get you into legal trouble.

Comment: @coteyr I think it was clear from the question that "breaking a rule" wasn't meant in complete isolation, but as "breaking [only] a rule". Obviously, breaking a rule which happens to line up with a law is _also_ breaking the law, and therefore not 'less serious than a "crime"'.

Comment: But that's my point. Ever get a parking ticket at a University. You broke a rule, but not a law. Ever park in the wrong spot at high school and have that thing put on your tire. You broke a school policy, not a law. The law allows them to make up such policies, but even though there may be legal issues laws are not broken. See also OSHA, for a federal example of things like that. Even the minimum working age on family farms is not set in law but policy. You can break a policy and need a lawyer, you can break a law and need a lawyer. Especially the question title leaves that open...

Comment: ... Meaning that if your talking about a legal issue, that is not quite breaking a law, but is instead breaking a policy, it would be an *infraction* (perhapse) that could be very serious, even though no crime was committed.

Comment: @coteyr I'm honestly confused.  I thought the question was about non-legalities.

Comment: "[Infractions](https://www.lectlaw.com/mjl/cl008.htm), sometimes known as regulatory offenses, **are the least serious class of crime** in the criminal law system of the United States."

Comment: @Mazura While that is a useful legal definition, the term "infraction" certainly has a more general meaning which addresses this question appropriately.  Any organization with rules might have its own concept of "infractions" against them, regardless of any associated issues in the legal system.

Answer (score 26):

If it's not actually breaking any rules but is simply a social "miscue," it would be considered a [**faux pas**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faux%20pas):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : BLUNDER
>
> - Long, hot soaks in winter are a classic *faux pas*, since exposure to extreme heat after having been in the cold can cause small visible blood vessels to appear at the skin's surface. —Elle
>
> *especially* : a social blunder
>
> - . . . when I sauntered into the main dining room for my first breakfast, I realized I was the only person showing his legs. Careless *faux pas*, or was I being overly sensitive to the local culture? —David Swanson
> - Campaigning last year seemed to convince her that she can venture out alone without making costly *faux pas*. —Time Magazine
> - It was not until I'd covered about fifty kilometers that I committed my most terrible social *faux pas* yet: I overtook another cyclist. —Polly Evans
>
> Arriving too early would be a serious *faux pas*.
>   according to an oft-told story, the queen set a guest at ease about a *faux pas* by politely imitating it

Comment: Note to English learners: even though _faux pas_ looks like French and is pronounced in the French way, it is perfectly acceptable to casually incorporate it into any English speech, whether formal or informal.

Comment: That said, *faux pas* is used to describe things that are embarrassing or that are otherwise social missteps -- pink hair for a high schooler wouldn't have fallen into that category when I was in high school, as crazy hair colors were quite popular among my peers

Comment: I wouldn't use faux pas for something done in the full knowledge that it is against the rules or social expectations. With a faux pas, you don't aim for the negative reactions but rather find out too late that your actions lead to such reactions.

Answer (score 24):

If it's not really against the rules, or even if it is but it's not something that would get you expelled, you could just call it a

**no no**

which kind of implies it's socially unacceptable [even if only to the teachers, not the pupils.]

As to 'talking down' as mentioned in comments [which i really don't understand], if someone were to say, "Can I bring my dog in the shop? He won't be any nuisance." then the answer could easily be, "I'm sorry, that's a no no. I'm afraid we don't allow it, except guide dogs."
If you did, I doubt anyone would call the police. I doubt it's even actually illegal, but it's certainly socially unacceptable.

'Violation' isn't used for anything so minor in the UK, it sounds a bit like you'd be in handcuffs for it.
"Violation of human rights" or other similar legalese, would be a predominant use for it in the UK.
Violations are committed **against** you, not **by** you.

Comment: This is OK for children of preschool age; after that, it will often be perceived as "talking down" to the target, and demeaning. If you tell me that crossing against the light is a "no no", I'm going to think you're a bit of an «crude characterisation omitted».

Comment: I guess that depends whether crossing against the lights is some kind of offence where you live. "Jaywalking" doesn't exist in the UK, nor is there any law against crossing when the lights are against you [as a pedestrian]. & I really don't understand your "talking down" idea at all.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - I disagree with your assessment, and your crude characterization, too. While it may have an informal feel with childish overtones, it still gets borrowed in the adult world. Precedents abound, e.g., _Using the same password for multiple accounts, sharing passwords, keeping sticky notes on your monitor with login information, or just having a weak password in general are [**big no-no’s**](https://www.calyptix.com/top-threats/password-security-how-to-thwart-hackers-with-a-strong-password/) when it comes to cyber security._

Comment: +1 a **no-no** fits well into OP's scenario.

Comment: Indeed, my only nitpick (which I'm not even sure is valid) is that I would expect it to be hyphenated (*no-no*) rather than open (*no no*).

Comment: "no-no" (hyphenated), due to it being derived from "baby talk", has a *strong* connotative nuance that I would be careful of in context here. @J.R. 's citation, for example, is intentionally using it to cast a highly informal and simplistic tone in an effort to make the topic in question seem more accessible/simplistic, but it can easily read as either excessively juvenile or excessively condescending (to the point of being crass if not clearly tongue in cheek) depending on specific usage. Inappropriate to use if the speaker is in at all a formal context, short of Jeff's "preschooler" example.

Answer (score 23):

**Misdemeanor**

A minor wrongdoing.
*"The player can expect a lengthy suspension for his latest misdemeanor"*

A misdemeanor is against written rules, but not quite bad enough to be a crime.

Comment: A misdemeanor is a crime.

Comment: @JamieClinton There is a figurative sense of "minor wrongdoing" though...

Comment: @ColleenV yes, but in the context of a crime.

Comment: I thought of "misdemeanor" too when I read the question title, but the question body asks for a different word, many of which have been given in other answers already.

Comment: In the US a misdemeanour is a crime, but in the UK crimes are no longer classified in this way and the word can be used to mean any minor wrongdoing as stated in this answer.

Comment: Be aware if you're going to choose this word that it's spelt differently in USA from everywhere else.

Comment: I also considered "misdemeanor", but rejected it as too loaded, as in many places it is a legal term that is part of the "spectrum" of legal violations:  *felony → misdemeanor → infraction*.  In these places "infraction" is the term used for violation of law that is not serious enough to be considered "criminal", such as jaywalking or speeding, and which normally results in a fine, not incarceration.

Comment: For a school, this sounds really silly. Even if the word no longer means a crime in the UK under Common Law. It reeks of legalism and government. And it way over the top here.

Comment: @Andrew - Those are *petty crimes*. That's about how far down you can go if the OP uses the word "crime" instead of *offense* (using the secondary definition that's subjective, rather than that of legalities).

Comment: @Mazura  Either I'm misunderstanding your comment, or you are unclear on the distinction between *misdemeanor* and *infraction*.  "Petty crimes" are still criminal behavior, subject to various penalties and a criminal record.  In some jurisdictions, multiple misdemeanors can even result in felony charges, and jail time.  In comparison, no number of *infractions* ever results in actual *criminal* charges.  [More information](https://www.lectlaw.com/mjl/cl008.htm)

Comment: @Andrew In U.S. federal law, a single misdemeanor can result in prison time, up to one year. That's actually the distinction between a felony and a misdemeanor in federal law, as I recall (misdemeanor: incarceration <= 1 year, felony > 1 year.)

Answer (score 15):

In many areas of the United States, this will be characterised as a ***violation***. Often, *what* it is a violation *of* will be specified; for example, dyeing one’s hair pink is often a *violation of the school dress code*; dropping trash on the street is a *violation of sanitation regulations*, and so on.

Comment: This only works, though, if there is some written code prohibiting the behavior. In the OP's scenario, for example, if there is no school dress code that specifies "no pink or green hair," then "violation" isn't so apropos.

Comment: The single word "violation" doesn't fit in the OP's sentence. You always need to say "violation of the rules" or similar.

Comment: I think this answer is at least as good as my suggestion: infraction.  They are basically synonyms.  People say things like "that's a violation" 'of the rules' is implicit.  It doesn't sound right in this specific sentence for reasons I can't explain but still helpful.

Comment: One can hardly read through this chapter of answers without wondering whether they might be useful to the Vatican in consigning sinners to suitable periods in purgatory or the appropriate circle of hell.

Comment: @J.R. The OP, when you include the title, actually says it is against the rules. There thus is a written code that is being violated.

Comment: @trlkly - [Not all rules are written rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspoken_rule).

Answer (score 8):

peccadillo
Plural: peccadillos (seems to be preferred by some) or peccadilloes

Merriam Webster
definition: a slight offense

Slang: a no-no

A few examples from the press:

> [Payback Pecadillos + The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2005/06/05/magazine/payback-peccadilloes.html)
>
> **Hanging It Out in Public: Papandreou's peccadilloes**
>   Papandreou's
>   peccadilloes may bring his downfall
>   [Time Magazine](http://content.time.com/time/magazine/0,9263,7601881219,00.html)
>
> The British [establishment] needs to give more power to the provinces
>   and reduce the power of London in its economy and polity. It also
>   needs to address the concerns of the left-behind as a matter of
>   priority rather than luxuriating in the peccadilloes of the
>   cosmopolitan elite.
>   [The Economist](https://www.economist.com/bagehots-notebook/2018/06/12/some-thoughts-on-the-crisis-of-liberalism-and-how-to-fix-it)
>
> Pirsig’s references to the peculiarities, peccadilloes, and power of
>   the university are frequent and unmistakable.
>    [The Los Angeles Times
>   Review of Books](https://lareviewofbooks.org/article/zen-and-the-art-of-a-higher-education/#!)

Comment: You know, I have known the word since I was a child. I am a fluent Spanish speaker and only just realized that pecadillo (only one c) means a little sin. Funny how these things work.

Comment: -1 for *peccadillo*. I've never heard this in my life, as a native English speaker. It's definitely not common, and probably not a good choice here.

Comment: @ell: Your limited vocabulary shouldn't be grounds for downvoting.  +1 to counter.

Comment: @ell What's a body to say? :)

Comment: @kjhughes - I'm not normally in favor of "countervoting," but you sure picked a good place to exercise your right to do so. (I'm even less in favor of downvoting for the favor of enlightenment. In my experience here, most learners appreciate learning new words, even if they happen to be relatively obscure or quaint.)

Comment: @Lambie Since when should we trust some random newspapers on English usage? : )

Comment: @userr2684291 It's not usage, it's vocabulary. Sorry, I  know you are being funny. Me, too. :)

Comment: @ell *pecadillo* actually fits this situation perfectly.  Sure, it's not a common word, but it *is* a word, and one I've known about since I can remember.  I suspect the UK press is more fond of it than the American press, but then they've always seemed to have more fun.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for that. There seems to be much confusion over the register to use here: legal, formal, informal, religious, social gaffes. I should probably revamp my answer to reflect that idea of register. Or even just add social gaffe. [that'll rile 'em up.] But it is just too hot here on the East Coast. :)

Answer (score 5):

If it is *not* strictly against the rules, but a silly thing to do that's generally frowned upon, I would probably use the word **indiscretion**.

From [the ODE](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/indiscretion):

> **indiscretion**
>   /ɪndɪˈskrɛʃ(ə)n/, noun
>   Behaviour or speech that is indiscreet or displays a lack of good judgement.

Comment: Or, since it's not mentioned anywhere else here, simply "frowned upon" itself!

Answer (score 2):

Dyeing your hair pink _________ in secondary school.

● The suggested answers to this question:

> 1. is a **minor infringement**
> 2. is a **minor infraction**
> 3. is an act of **juvenile delinquency**
> 4. is not (officially) **allowed**
> 5. is **a no-no**
> 6. **is a breach/transgression**
> 7. **is a serious breach / transgression (as Andrew said)**

● We can also use these sentences in order to deliver the order:

> 1. Several of the girls were dying their hair pink, **in contravention** of the school rules on dress and makeup .
> 2. Dyeing your hair pink is **strictly prohibited** inside the school.

Comment: Also, *infringement* was the first word I thought of when I saw this question, and this is the only answer to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

Having read all the comments above, I have a sense that we have gone overboard in synonyms for rule-breaking. At risk of being accused of British understatement, ~I would say "Dyeing your hair pink is an **error** in secondary school".

Please note the spelling of "dyeing"

Comment: The wrong thing to do, yes. But an error? Hmm.

Answer (score 2):

One correct word is just
**[wrong](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=wrong)** (AHD)
*adj.*

> **4.** Not fitting or suitable; inappropriate or improper: said the wrong thing.
>   **5.** Not in accord with established usage, method, or procedure: the wrong way to shuck clams.

"Dying your hair pink is **wrong** in secondary school."

In the sense, "it's not the done thing;"  "it's against the convention."

Any of the above alternatives may also work: *not in accord with established usage, not fitting, inappropriate, improper.*

Answer (score 1):

If it's against the rules of the school:

**violation of school rules**

If it's a forbidden by social customs:

**taboo**

Answer (score -1):

Well I like a long list and here's mine (I think it's interesting to consider who the speaker might be describing this act with varying degrees of disapprobation, it could be a peer, a tutor, a stern head of school, a parent, a sibling, a sibling, a priest, even a lawyer):

> sin, misdemeanour, offence, crime, peccadillo, violation, infraction,
>   transgression, error, lapse, fault, infringement, disgrace, outrage,
>   slip, indiscretion, wrongdoing.

Comment: I think this answer would be more helpful to a learner if you provided a short synopsis of when each might be especially fitting or appropriate. I think you make an excellent point about who is doing the talking. A parent wouldn't necessarily talk about pink hair the same way a school official might.

Answer (score -1):

Crimes are generally separated into two distinct levels depending on the seriousness of the offense. These levels are **Felonies** and **Misdemeanors**. Both levels are broken down further into different classes. For example, a misdemeanor can be of class 1, 2, or 3, where class 3 is the least serious. There are minimum and maximum penalties for each class of felony and misdemeanor. These min and max guidelines are intended to guide judges in their ruling and hopefully provide some semblance of evenly distributed justice within a society.

The most minor offense may be called a **summary offense**. This includes minor infractions such as loitering and small value retail theft. A conviction of a summary offense usually results in a fine.

The punishment for being convicted of a felony or misdemeanor will vary. Conviction of a misdemeanor usually results in a fine. However, other factors like the seriousness of the crime or a history of previous offenses may increase the punishment. Additional punishment may include community service, house arrest, a work release program, jail time, and of course, more fines. It is also common to lose privileges such as a driver's license. This is especially true for offenses involving drugs and alcohol.

An act that is not illegal but is "against the rules" or "frowned upon" could be considered a wrongdoing or violation. This depends on the nature of the circumstances surrounding the action. For example, feeding the ducks at a pond where signage prohibiting this action is clearly posted may result in your immediate removal from the area or even a costly fine. There may not be any penal code prohibiting such action but if the locality has decided to enforce this rule then your **violation** may result in punishment.

Comment: If you're going to get into the legal terms, shouldn't you mention "criminal offense" versus "civil offense"?

Comment: Warning: This answer is US-centric. In the UK or Ireland the words "felony" and "misdemeanour" are not used (or at least not in this way). Reference: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felony). My very brief research doesn't extend to other English speaking countries.

Comment: @Wildcard, Yes - you are correct. I should mention what a tort is and how it fits into the OP's question but I don't like this thread I'm getting downvoted for trying to be helpful.  - It is based on the US legal system, which varies from state to state

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would guess the downvotes are because your answer is not targeted to the particular purpose of *this* site, which is to help English language learners (not lawyers).  You should read the [tour page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) because this isn't a traditional forum, and these aren't traditional "threads."